# Android Sax Parser not handling empty tags properly

Tags: android, saxparser

I am using `SAXParser` in android, but somehow when whitespace or no text between tags the parser skips it and uses the previous tag value for it. What i am doing wrong.

Comment: Please improve your question with the code and xml string your are parsing..otherwise I dont think you will get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Solved the problem, just adjusted the parser a bit now its running clean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will skip the empty tags. you need to make change before preparing the xml. Put one check that if any tag is empty the fill it with any unused char ( for i.e. "-" ). I use same logic for my programs.

Answer (score 0):

i think in

```
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
        if(this.mCurrentClient!=null){

           if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("clientId")){
               yourObject.setmClientId(mBuilder.toString());
           }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
               yourObject.setmTitle(mBuilder.toString());
           }
                       mBuilder.setLength(0);
      }
```

mBuilder is object of string builder i think you should add the last statement in the above code

hope that could help you.